# How restrict the access to some page in website for specific IP or domain names

Tags: c#, asp.net, payment-gateway

I am using payment gateway in my website. For payment, user redirect to bank page and come back to bank-callback.html. After come back, site automatically activate services that ordered by user.
I want restrict the access to page bank-callback.html to bank IP (or in better manner to bank domain name).
In this case `UrlRefferer` is null when user come back from bank payment gateway to bank-callback.html page.
Furthermore we know `UrlRefferer` is not safe method for detection. Do you know any solution?

Answer (score 0):

UrlReferrer is probably null because the bank's website uses HTTPS. Referrer headers are not passed on in this case.

Your simplest approach is to check [Request.UserHostAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.userhostaddress.aspx) and reject the request if it is not from the bank's range of IP addresses.

Edit: I've misunderstood - I thought the bank called this page directly like Paypal or SagePay do. You should probably speak to your bank, they will have a mechanism to do this securely.

Comment: Ok but when i checked UserHostAddress it is give user ip address not bank ip